# Count execute()s successfully performed PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I currently use a function within a class to insert data into a database, and if each row is successfully insert (from csv file) a message is logged (logMessage function), to show which row was or was not successful. However I would like the count of the **successful** executions that have been imported into the database. And I'm having a bit of trouble

```
public function insertData($data, $name, $quantity, $date){

        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(data, name, quantity, date) VALUES(:data, :name, :quantity, :date)";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(":data", $data);
            $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
            $stmt->bindParam(":quantity", $quantity);
            $stmt->bindParam(":date", $date);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                FileProcessor::logMessage("Data imported: <b>$data</b>");
            } else {
                FileProcessor::logMessage("Not Imported <b>$data</b>");
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            FileProcessor::logMessage("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you think there are unsuccessful inserts? what is the error message?

Comment: It's using user supplied CSV data, blank fields will result in an error message for null data being inserted

Comment: Why can't you handle these errors, either by means of either checking input data or changing table structure to allow empty fields? An erroneous query is an exceptional case, and your application should never count on "expected" error. You have to always handle such case before calling a query

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking the same. I will validate any errors processing any information to a database. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for rowCount(), see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: That just returns 1 for each row. Not using a loop

Answer (score 0):

Return the rowCount() in each function call and sum up all the return values.

For more, you must show how you call the function, not the function itself. I suppose you call it from a loop.